# Why vlookup in excel either returned NA or mismatched?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have two tables as below. I tried several times and could not understand why Vlookup cannot work.

```
EE ID     Application
000101     
000121   
000137   
000158   
000175   
000182   
000209
```

Table 2 for match

```
EE ID   Application
000182   o
000223   o
000292   o
000305   o
000311   o
000314   o
000353   o
000356   o
```

I just wanna match the o in table two to table one. I used like this

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Off!A:B,2)   and get all #N/A
=VLOOKUP(A2,off!A:B,2,)  and get lots of mismatch.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: VLOOKUP only looks in the first column of the `off!A:B` range and then returns the columns to the right.  If you swap the columns in the `off` table so that application is on the left it will work.  If you can't change the data then use INDEX and MATCH to do the lookup.

Comment: Is the top table you posted the one you're trying to add the `VLOOKUP()` to ?  What's the expected result you're looking for?  What table is on the `Off` sheet?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `VLOOKUP` can indeed return values to the left of the lookup column. You just need to provide the range as a series of arrays. I've probably not explained very well, but Google it and I'm sure you'll find a better explanation.

Comment: You seem to have a flawed understanding of `VLookup`. 1), you have to be looking up something that occurs in BOTH sheets. There is only one "EE ID" value (000182) that is common.; so it is the ONLY VLookup that would be successful. 2), the parameter ` [is_sorted]` seems innocuous and almost useless, but it will distort your results if improperly used. The default value of `[is_sorted]` is TRUE, but in most cases it should be set as False (or 0). So the correct formula is `=VLOOKUP(A2,Off!A:B,2,0)` - the result will be #N/A until you reach row 7, when the result should be "o".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, OFF!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aRFC_N_1_uIkU5RitKn0QWaiARroyu8bpN-OMPSOK1g/edit#gid=494483274)